# Can't apply monospaced font to listings (when using pdflatex)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, listings, typewriter

I'm a newbie to LaTeX and I can't find the cause of a problem described below.

---

I need to insert several C++ code snippets into my document, so I use the **listings** package for this purpose. The compiler is **pdflatex**. Everything works, but the monospaced font just doesn't apply to code within **lstlisting** environment.

- I have already tried to fix this with including the **beramono** package. But the **\ttfamily** command just seems "ignorant" of it.
- Also, I can't use the **courier** package, because the corresponding **\texttt** command can't be used in **basicstyle** parameter of **\lstset**. So I use the **\ttfamily**. But it doesn't work:-)

Here is my "simplified" LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[beramono]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style

\usepackage{arsclassica} % Modifies the Classic Thesis package
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Just in case: The main document language is Russian, so I use cp1251.
% Of course, the C++ code doesn't have any cyrillic letters
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel} 


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


% Here I change the default font, because the \textbf command doesn't work on it
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona} 

\definecolor{BackgroundColor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, % Doesn't work !
  language=C++,
  backgroundcolor=\color{BackgroundColor},
  tabsize=4,
  captionpos=b,
  %tabsize=3,
  frame=lines,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
  stringstyle=\color{red}
  }

 \begin{document}

Example of code snippet:

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
#include <Bo/services/Ucntl.h>

ssize_t
__attribute__((nonnull(1))
AorpRelease(
    aorp_object_t aThis,
    aorp_opflags_t Flags /* = 0 */,
    struct aorp_error *anErrPtr /* = NULL */
    );
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

What I have in result: [image: this code definitely doesn't look cute]

Note: I'm not OK with just leaving it serif. The ampersand is unsatisfiable.

I hope someone of you guys will help to figure out what's wrong.

P.S. I am not desperate enough to try this: http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm Looks quite painful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should switch to UTF-8, rather than `cp1251`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/fvm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 47.
```

that you shouldn't disregard.

Solution: tell LaTeX you're not using Cyrillic in listings.

```
basicstyle=\normalsize\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily,
```

Full code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[beramono]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style

\usepackage{arsclassica} % Modifies the Classic Thesis package
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Just in case: The main document language is Russian, so I use cp1251.
% Of course, the C++ code doesn't have any cyrillic letters
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel} 


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


% Here I change the default font, because the \textbf command doesn't work on it
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{iwona} 

\definecolor{BackgroundColor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{OliveGreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\normalsize\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily,
  language=C++,
  backgroundcolor=\color{BackgroundColor},
  tabsize=4,
  captionpos=b,
  %tabsize=3,
  frame=lines,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
  stringstyle=\color{red}
  }

 \begin{document}

Example of code snippet:

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
#include <Bo/services/Ucntl.h>

ssize_t
__attribute__((nonnull(1))
AorpRelease(
    aorp_object_t aThis,
    aorp_opflags_t Flags /* = 0 */,
    struct aorp_error *anErrPtr /* = NULL */
    );
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Grazie for your answer! I had some C++ comments written in Russian, but it  didn't hurt to remove them. After that, everything worked out. Thanks again